# How to setup Adobe Analytics(Omniture) feeds to Google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, adobe-analytics

Is there any direct service which can be used to write data feeds from Adobe Analytics (Omniture) to Google cloud storage bucket or any alternative solution apart from setting up ftp server on gcp instance?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't.

Datafeeds currently can either deliver directly to an AWS S3 bucket or FTP/SFTP account (note, I didn't list FTPS as its unsupported).

You'll likely need to setup a jump point somewhere - either in AWS or an FTP site in Google as you suggest. I realize this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it at least gets you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the party but you might find some help setting up your own Data Feed transfer process and data loading in BigQuery in Python at https://analyticsmayhem.com/adobe-analytics/data-feeds-google-bigquery/. Let me know if you have any questions.